# Getting The State History of all Order and export

Tags: sales-order, export, reports, order-status, history

Is it possible to get the state history of all orders and add it in a new column on sales report?
I have a module similar to the core and I'd like to add a column with all states of each order.

```
class Sales_Enhanced_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid{

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sales_enhanced_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
            'city'       => 'city',
            'country_id' => 'country_id'
        ))
        ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
            'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
        ))
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'fullname',
            'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
            array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'products',
            '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                    AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
            array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id'));


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('sales_enhanced');
    $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

    $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Order #'),
        'index'  => 'increment_id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('purchased_on', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Purchased On'),
        'type'   => 'datetime',
        'index'  => 'created_at'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('products', array(
        'header'       => $helper->__('Products Purchased'),
        'index'        => 'products',
        'filter_index' => '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('fullname', array(
        'header'       => $helper->__('Name'),
        'index'        => 'fullname',
        'filter_index' => 'CONCAT(customer_firstname, \' \', customer_lastname)'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('city', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('City'),
        'index'  => 'city'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('country', array(
        'header'   => $helper->__('Country'),
        'index'    => 'country_id',
        'renderer' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_country'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Customer Group'),
        'index'  => 'customer_group_code'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header'        => $helper->__('Grand Total'),
        'index'         => 'grand_total',
        'type'          => 'currency',
        'currency_code' => $currency
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
        'index'  => 'shipping_description'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_status', array(
        'header'  => $helper->__('Status'),
        'index'   => 'status',
        'type'    => 'options',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
    ));



    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportEnhancedCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportEnhancedExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();} 

   public function getGridUrl(){return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));}}
```

Any suggestions will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution to my own question.
I create my own Grid in the same path of the grid.php from core on my local

/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php (My)
/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php (original)

Add just a litle code in `function _prepareColumns`

> ```
>   $this->addColumn('history', array(
>   'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('History status'),
>   'type'  => 'text',
>   'renderer' => new Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Rendererhistory()
>    ));
> ```

And create in the same path `/Renderhistory.php` whit code

> ```
> class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Rendererhistory extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
> {
>    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
>    {
>      $orderId = $row->getId();
>      $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
>      $history = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection();
>      $conc="";
>        foreach($history as $k)
>        {
>           $conc .=" ".$k->getStatus();
>        }
>        return $conc;
>     }
> }
> ```

And go to `Sales` - `Orders`